# Sql Server JDBC Driver Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I am trying to set preparestament parameter  dynamically based on parameter count like below, SQL server JDBC driver give me error.

```
preparedStatement = root.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?");
if(preparedStatement.getParameterMetaData()!=null){ //exception at this line

//do some logic
}
```

Error :

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near
>   the keyword 'BETWEEN'.

Same Code works fine for **Mysql** jdbc driver.

(I am using sqljdbc41.jar for mssql).

Can any one have this kind of issue or any solution?

Comment: `DATE` is a keyword, maybe you need to escape that in SQL Server e.g. `"DATE"` or the non-standard `[DATE]` that SQL Server uses.

Answer (score 0):

DATE is a reserved word, you need to enclose it in quotes:

```
root.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE \"DATE\" BETWEEN ? AND ?");
```

Comment: unfortunately its not working, because preparedStatement.executeQuery() already works so its not issue of reserved keyword..it only fails if i used getParameterMetaData()

Comment: @JekinKalariya Are you 100% sure? This is an error that occurs when executing a query. Did you try the suggested solution?

Comment: Yes  BackSlash I tried it as soon as you post, and its work even if i not replace Date with \"Date\", here problem is not in query syntax its something that getParameterMetaData method is going to do some logic inside..